# Cocoa Dock fires NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification

Tags: cocoa, dock, nsapplication

When changing the dock position Cocoa is firing a NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification:

The problem is that as for [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it should be raised only when

> Posted when the configuration of the displays attached to the computer
>   is changed. The configuration change can be made either
>   programmatically or when the user changes settings in the Displays
>   control panel. The notification object is sharedApplication. This
>   notification does not contain a userInfo dictionary.

So if you want to update your application windows when attach a new display (e.g. changing/moving the frame of some HUD window/etc), you will have a fake notification coming the dock.
Also there's no userInfo dictionary attached to this notification, so I had no chance to check whenever was the dock or a new display controller.

So how to handle this?

A possible solution is to check the [NSScreen mainScreen] size when the notification si fired.
If this NSSize changes, that notification comes from a new display attached, not from the dock:

```
static NSSize mainScreenSize;

-(void)handleApplicationDidChangeScreenParameters:(NSNotification *)notification {


    NSSize screenSize = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size;


    if( screenSize.width != mainScreenSize.width || screenSize.height != mainScreenSize.height ) { // screen size changed

        mainScreenSize =  [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size;
        [myWindowController updateContent];
        [[myWindow contentView] setNeedsDisplay:YES]; // update custom window

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notification is fired because the main screen's `visibleFrame` (which excludes the space occupied by the Dock) depends on the position of the Dock.

So if the `visibleFrame` of the main screen changes, you can be sure that the notification is the result of the Dock being moved.