# How to get resolution change event in swift?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I try to make an app, and now i shoud  make some changes when screen resolution will change, but i coudn't find  how to intercept this event.

Do you have any ideea  how can i take that event?

Comment: What do you mean by "screen resolution change"? A device's screen resolution doesn't change easily... :P

Comment: sory, i shoud mention i need that for osX.

Comment: My fault as well, I shouldn't assume everything is about iOS. :)

Comment: You should add OS X to your subject and as a tag of your question. I vaguely remember that there's a way to do this, but don't have time to hunt for it now. I'll try to come back to this question later...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdidchangescreenparametersnotification?language=objc) is posted when the configuration of the displays attached to the computer is changed, so
you can register for that notification, e.g. with

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification,
    object: NSApplication.sharedApplication(),
    queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        notification -> Void in
        println("screen parameters changed")
}
```

Note that there can be various reasons why this notification is
fired, e.g. a change in the dock size (as observed in [Cocoa Dock fires NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901826/cocoa-dock-fires-nsapplicationdidchangescreenparametersnotification)), so you have to
"remember" the old resolution and compare it with the new resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4:

The `didChangeScreenParametersNotification` is posted when the configuration of the displays attached to the computer is changed.

Inside the `func applicationDidFinishLaunching()` in AppDelegate class or `func viewDidLoad()` in ViewController class, insert the following code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSApplication.didChangeScreenParametersNotification,
                                       object: NSApplication.shared,
                                       queue: OperationQueue.main) {
                                       notification -> Void in
                                       print("screen parameters changed")}
```

I personally, used it to center the position of my application when switching between the Mac and the external screen.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Narendra Jadhav, thank you for your advice. I'll try my best to contribute to the community.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the updated Swift 3 code:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParameters,
                                                            object: NSApplication.shared(),
                                                            queue: OperationQueue.main) {
                                                                notification -> Void in
                                                                print("screen parameters changed")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Code for Swift 5+

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    forName: NSApplication.didChangeScreenParametersNotification,
    object: NSApplication.shared,
    queue: .main) { notification in
        self.adjustUIIfNeeded()
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use a string?

Comment: I added this code some time back, I will update this soon, thanks :)