# How can I observe visibleFrame changes in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos

I am reading the size of visibleFrame in my current code, the issue that I have is that I cannot read the updated value of visibleFrame if my user decides to change macOS dock size, which effect the visibleFrame. So the first thing comes to my mind using a timer for firing a funcation to read the visibleFrame but as you know this could not be the convenient way, so I am looking a way for observing this value changes alive or via a notification.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var myScreen: MyScreen = MyScreen.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if let size: CGSize = myScreen.visibleFrame?.size {
            Text("visibleFrame size: " + String(describing: size))
        }

    }
}



class MyScreen: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared: MyScreen = MyScreen()
    
    var visibleFrame: NSRect? {
        return NSScreen.main?.visibleFrame
    }

}
```

How to solve the issue without using a timer?

Comment: Maybe this helps: [How to get resolution change event in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412481/how-to-get-resolution-change-event-in-swift)

Comment: Try TimelineView

Comment: @Willeke: That was exactly what I was looking for, I got a new issue now, with this way you mentioned I can get and decode the notification for the updated values if user make some changes for dock, now if user did not made any change at all, can we make this notification get posted just for reading current values that notification can give us? I mean I need some data to fill my variables and I do not want keep them nil until user decide to update the dock.

Comment: If you can't fill your variables without a notification then you can post the notification yourself.